# What does the WEIGHT value shown in Community Moderators Elections Results mean?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

In every **Community Moderator Election Results** ([ex: 2017 results](https://www.opavote.com/ballots/5927932925050880/0?p=4)), we can see that there is a **weight** for each *user voting record*.

[image: Screenshot of the 5th, 6th, 7th, and 8th ballot in the 2017 Moderator election. The 5th ballot with one vote for Travis J has a weight of 96, the 6th ballot with one vote for vaultah has a weight of 75, the 7th ballot with one vote for Baum mit Augen has a weight of 115, and the 8th ballot with one vote for Alexander O'Mara has a weight of 134.]

What is it, and how is it calculated ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's just the number of users that filled the ballot like this.

Your first example means that 96 voters selected Travis J as their first choice and nobody as second and third choice, thus the ballot with Travis being the first and only choice gets the weight 96.

Or another example: 188 voters selected Andy as their first choice, Cody Gray as second and Rob as third, so the ballot with *"1. Andy, 2. Cody Gray, 3. Rob"* gets weight 188.

If you sum up all weights you should end up with a total of 30582 votes.

Comment: And here I thought they all had to fly to SO's offices and step on a scale...

Comment: @Mena We vote for the mods with the most gravitas.

Comment: @Michael sounds like a good criterion :)